# angularjs directive not responding to event binding in link function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

[This plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/LeUiRE8RtVy2zp8NPkmu) refers.

I have two simple element (`restrict: "E"`) directives, `incButtonOne` and `incButtonTwo`, that track and display the number of times it has been clicked. They both implement local controllers and have isolate scope. The two directives accomplish the same thing but with slightly different implementations:

- `incButtonOne`'s template includes a `ng-click` directive in the tag to facilitate the click counting by calling a function in the directive's controller
- `incButtonTwo` implements a `link` function to register a click event handler that calls the incrementing function in the directive's controller

They both work. Kind of. The problem is that `incButtonTwo`'s displayed value is only updated after `incButtonOne` is clicked, i.e. the value is in fact updated (this can be confirmed by uncommenting the `alert` statement on line 45) but it's not being displayed until some other action is performed.

I would just like to understand why this is happening and how to fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you manually register event handler you must manually call **scope.$apply()** function like this

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  element.on('click', function() {
     scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.count++;
     });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Stanislav Demydiuk said, you must use `$apply()` to get your binding to update. And using your function "increment", here is what you get:

```
element.on("click", function() {
     scope.$apply(increment);
});
```

**Note:**
In your example, if the click on the first button makes your second button update, it's because  of *ng-click* event, which is wrapped in `$scope.$apply()` (see [this article](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html)).